# A closed-form formula for Cov(X,Y) when X and Y are normal random vectors?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, covariance

I cannot figure out one step given in my textbook, [1] *Mixed Models. Theory and Applications* by E. Demidenko.

I study the Linear Mixed Effects (LME) model in the following form: 
$$\mathbf{y_i}=\mathbf{X_i\beta}+\mathbf{Z_ib_i} + \varepsilon _i.$$
It is assumed that
$$\mathbf{b_i} \sim \mathit{N}(\mathbf{0},\sigma ^2\mathbf{D})$$
and, eventually, that the LME model with normally distributed random variables can be written in marginal form as 
$$\mathbf{y_i} \sim \mathit{N}(\mathbf{X_i\beta},\sigma ^2\mathbf{(I+Z_iDZ'_i)}) \tag{2.13}$$

What puzzles me is the part about $\operatorname{cov}(\mathbf{b_i},\mathbf{y_i})$ ([1], p. 148.):

> Assuming normal distribution, from model (2.13) it follows that
>   $\operatorname{cov}(\mathbf{b_i},\mathbf{y_i}) = \sigma ^2\mathbf{DZ'_i}$.

I guess that this follows **some known fact about covariance between two normal random vectors (?)** but I cannot figure out where from we do have this $\operatorname{cov}(\mathbf{b_i},\mathbf{y_i})$ formula.